# MVC @foreach and JavaScript Confusion

Tags: javascript, asp.net-mvc, twitter-bootstrap, razor

I'm trying to make a button in a Bootstrap popover that passes a Razor value to another JavaScript function called `killDatabase` when running through a Razor `foreach`. The code produces a list of buttons that you can select but I also want to be able to hit a button and delete one of the options. The code doesn't throw any errors, and everything works perfectly except the fact that any of the delete buttons will always delete the last element, not the one that it's supposed to be associated with. I'm assuming this is because the function gets called on an `onclick` and so at that point `@str` is just the last element's name, but I'm wondering if there's any way to store that value to be unique for each element? I've tried adding a JavaScript variable within the `foreach` but still ran into the same problem.

```
<div class="btn-group-vertical btn-block" data-toggle="buttons" id="btns">
    @foreach (var str in Model)
    {

    <div id="popover-content" hidden>
        Are you sure you would like to permanently delete this query from the database?<br />
        <button onclick="killDatabase('@str')" class="btn btn-primary btn-sm" style="float:left; margin-bottom: 10px;">Yes</button>
        <button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary" style="float:left;">No</button>
    </div>
        <label class="btn btn-default" style="height:auto">
            <div class="form-group" style="height:auto; padding-bottom: 10px;">
                <input type="radio" name="query" value="@str" /> 
                <span class="pull-left">@str</span>
                <span class="pull-right"> 
                <button class="btn btn-sm btn-danger" style="margin-top:-2px;" data-toggle="popover" title="Confirm Deletion" data-placement="bottom">
                <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></button></span>
            </div>
        </label>

    }
</div>
```

Comment: Is this code within an external Javascript file? If so, you aren't going to be able to use any razor syntax (e.g. `@str`) to reference your server-side variables.

Comment: With the code you had shown, it is passing the str variable (the iterator in the loop) to your `killDatabase` method. What does the method do ? Are you seeing unique `str` variables rendered when you do a view source of the page ?

Comment: @RionWilliams Sorry, should have mentioned this is within a View, not external JavaScript. Like I said, everything else works fine, including the other references to `@str` except when I pass it to `killDatabase`

Comment: What does your `killDatabase` function look like? You should be able to easily look at the source to ensure that your `@str` values are being passed along correctly. Do you have any errors present in the Developer Tools (F12) when attempting to call the function?

Comment: @Shyju The `<input>` with `@str` as a value shows unique values, and if I do a `console.log` at the beginning of each, I see unique values as well It's only when I pass it to `killDatabase` with an `onclick`

Comment: when you put a console.log of the parameter passed to `killDatabase`, It is showing the correct value ? Then you have something wrong in the delete code where it is deleting the wrong item.

Comment: @RionWilliams right now it just prints whatever value is passed to it with a `console.log`

Comment: So it sounds like the actual function is passing its value as expected. Since the function is called `killDatabase` is it actually making either a server-side call via a POST or AJAX to perform this? There may be an issue with that subsequent call if that is the case.

Comment: @Shyju like I said, it's only when I do it through an `onclick`. I've tried printing the values as it runs and it works fine.

Comment: @RionWilliams once I get this working I'm planning on having it do an AJAX call, yes, but right now it just prints

Comment: So I'm failing to understand what is not working. If your existing `killDatabase` function only logs the parameter that was passed in and that seems to work, then I would assume that once you wire up your AJAX call, you could still just use that same parameter that was passed in, no?

Comment: Ok so new development, I neglected to mention that the code shown up top gets passed to another view via an AJAX call where it is appended to the page HTML. When just running this view, which I hadn't tried, sorry, it works. So now I think it's something with that first AJAX call

Comment: Plz add killDatabase function to question

Comment: @MohammadAkbari It's literally just

    function killDatabase(db){
        console.log(db);
    }

Answer (score 0):

So I'm going to close this question because it was me being really confused about AJAX. That's what it boiled down to: I had a bad AJAX call and I was trying to do things on a popover that was initialized after the page was loaded so any time I would try and use the `@str` value in that popup, it would only take the most recent value. I've reworked the code into a more streamlined, less buggy design, and it works fine now. Thanks to everyone who tried to help